# Convert Stdout to String

Tags: python, stdout

I'm trying to convert `sys.stdout.write` output into a string after printing it so that I can modify it and print it again later, but I'm having issues.

Here's my code so far:

```
import sys
import random

def write(s):
    sys.stdout.write(s)
    myOutput = sys.stdout(s)

i = random.randint(1,10)
write("\nMy number is "+str(i)+".")
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, it giving me the following error:

```
TypeError. "'PseudoOutputFile' object is not callable"
```

What I should do to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why not `myOutput = s`?

Answer (score 2):

But, you already have it as a string.  It's just `s`.  So replace:

```
myOutput = sys.stdout(s)
```

with:

```
myOutput = s
```

Also, if myOutput is intended to be global, then you will need to declare it inside the function as:

```
global myOutput
```

Comment: I didn't think that the formatting would stay the same if I didn't use sys.stdout.write, thank you very much for the fast answer! I feel kind of stupid for not seeing such an obvious solution, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick little example:

```
import sys

def main ():
    i=1
    sys.stdout.write("Value is %s" % i)
main()
```